# store array inside database column - laravel 5

Tags: arrays, database, laravel, store, records

My controller is:

```
public function store()
{
    $links = array();
    $html = new \Htmldom('http://randomsite.org');

    foreach($html->find('a') as $a) 
    {
        $links[] = $a->href;
    }

}
```

and i have the database table called result with field:

```
id
name
url (i want to put the array here)
desc
```

what I want is multiple records as number links

Comment: Serialize it http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am right. You need the solution to store data into database.

```
foreach($links as $link)
{
  $result= new Result;        //here Result is the model name for the table result
  $result->id =  $link[0];  //id
  $event->name = $link[1];  //name
  $event->url =  $link[2];  //url
  $event->desc = $link[3];  //desc
  $event->save();
}
```

Here you loop through each array of items and insert multiple rows in the table

Comment: Thank you man, you save me! i do a foreach and $result->url and stop, thank you again!